# Using byteArray with getPixel (no 's') then setPixelS

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, getpixel

Here is what I am trying to do:

- one byteArray (colorsByteArray) holds color values, that I created with the "getPixels" method;
- for every pixel on screen, I make calculations and depending on that I get a rank that I use to retrieve the proper color value inside colorsByteArray;
- finally, I write inside a second byteArray (pixelsByteArray) the color I just retrieved. Then I 'draw' this byteArray using the "setPixels" method.

Problem is I do not find the same image as if I simply wrote a "setPixel" for every pixel in my loop. The image I get is missing one line out of two, and is kind of repeated three times horizontally. Of course I guess I must be writing (or reading) something wrong from my second byteArray, but can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? Or even if my efforts are worth anything actually :-) cause I didn't find anything quite like this so far...
Thanks!

Here is a bit of my code to make things clearer:

```
 colorsByteArray = bitmDext.getPixels(new Rectangle(0, 0, myShadeBMD.width, 1));

 canvas.lock();
 for(var i:int = 0; i < STAGE_WIDTH; i++)
 {
     for(var j:int = 0; j < STAGE_HEIGHT; j++)
     {
         //make some calculation on each pixel to get the 'colorRank' uint value

         colorsByteArray.position = colorRank * 4;//unsigned int is 32 bytes, representing 4 slots of a byteArray
         var colorValue:uint = colorsByteArray.readUnsignedInt();

         //canvas.setPixel(i, j, colorValue);//works just fine

         pixelsByteArray.writeUnsignedInt(colorValue);
     }
 }

 pixelsByteArray.position = 0;
 var myRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, STAGE_WIDTH, STAGE_HEIGHT);
 canvas.setPixels(myRect, pixelsByteArray);

 canvas.unlock();
```

added a picture that may help:
http://www.oghel.com/pictures/stackOverflow/example3
the expected part is on the right, the wrong one on the left.

Comment: Looks like you made a typo, you've got `i < STAGE_HEIGHT` instead of `j < STAGE_HEIGHT`. Is this in your code as well or did you just type it incorrectly here?

Comment: Hello, yes it was a typo, I edited it, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @puggsoy but the typo was only in this post and not in my code ;-) So the problem remains unsolved.

Comment: Would you be able to post screenshots of the original image and the result? That would make it easier to identify what's going wrong.

Comment: @puggsoy yes I've done that already , editing my post ;-)
http://www.oghel.com/pictures/stackOverflow/example3 the expected part is on the right, the wrong one on the left.

Comment: Well, I have a hunch, but it's difficult to tell exactly what's going on here. Could you please explain exactly what `bitmDext` contains, what `myShadeBMD` is, what `STAGE_WIDTH` and `STAGE_HEIGHT` are (although I can guess), and how you're calculating colorRank. I want to test your code myself (it'll be easier to debug that way) but without knowing what all of these are, I can't.